# PFPush doesn't have sendPushInBackground

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, bolts-framework

I have just installed the Parse framework.

However I get strange errors : 
'PFPush' does not have a member named 'sendPushInBackground'

However this function IS in the header of Parse framework.

It seems that it doesn't recognize the function whenever it uses a BTTask. So I tried to add Bolts framework and FacebookSDK, only Bolt, only FacebookSDK but none of these helped me.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks